# ANDROID STUDIO- layout background (image) doesn't show

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout

everyone, first of all, I'm with a problem in my android project. I set an image as a layout background with the appropriate width (5.5), and when I run the application it appears white background instead of the intended image. The image is in at the drawable folder, all normal.

The image has the same dimensions of the layout (5.5)

Code:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@drawable/fundo"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_branco" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="450dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/advent_pro_thin"
        android:text="O automóvel ideal para si!"
        android:textColor="#E76C00"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please add the drawable as well?

Comment: looks like xml code doesn't have any issue, for better findings share your background image

Comment: Add your complete `.xml` file and maybe someone can help you.

Comment: Description update!!

Comment: I can out a gradient.xml as background but the image i cant....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load a whole image, I'd use the approach of having an `ImageView` at the root ViewGroup of the layout with both dimensions set to `match_parent`.

This will solve the issue of the image not loading with an added benefit of being able to define scale type (like `centerCrop`) which enables you to have a picture with any side ratio and be sure it'll fill the screen both vertically and horizontally.

Edit:

Proposed solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/fundo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_branco" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="450dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/advent_pro_thin"
        android:text="O automóvel ideal para si!"
        android:textColor="#E76C00"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the help! I tried but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: I'm glad you solved it! Do you know what was wrong with the initial image?

Comment: Hello, I think the problem was the resolution of the image and probably my phone when running the application could not process the same! Thank you